# overlayed animations in beamer using knitr

Tags: r, animation, latex, knitr, beamer

I'd like to create an animation in beamer using the knitr package and the chunk option `fig.show='animate'` with the figures being overlayed rather than replaced similar to how \multiinclude works by default.

A minimal non-working example would be the following (Rnw file) where I'd like each point to be added one-by-one to the existing plot in the animation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
<<fig.show='animate', fig.width=5, fig.height=5, size='tiny', out.width='.8\\linewidth', fig.align='center', echo=FALSE>>=
x = 1:2
plot(x,x,type="n")
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  points(x[i],x[i])
}
@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

From looking at the [knitr graphics manual](https://bitbucket.org/stat/knitr/downloads/knitr-graphics.pdf), it states the two sources of plots are `plot.new()` and `grid.newpage()`, but has a footnote to see `?recordPlot`. So I tried putting `recordPlot()` after the `points` command (and also adding a transparent background via `par(bg=NA)`, but this did not work as only a single plot is created.

A minimal working example is the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
<<fig.show='animate', fig.width=5, fig.height=5, size='tiny', out.width='.8\\linewidth', fig.align='center', echo=FALSE, fig.keep='all'>>=
x = 1:2
plot(x,x,type="n")
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  for (j in 1:i) points(x[j],x[j])
}
@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but this seems like overkill since each figure redraws the plot and all the preceding points.

Is there some way to get rid of the loop over `j`? or some other way to overlay plots in beamer/knitr? If yes, how can my code above be modified to make that happen?

Comment: that's a good suggestion that I hadn't tried. including `fig.keep='all'` allows me simplify the minimal working example (which I've updated), but in the non-working example, it only provide two plots: one with no points and one with all the points rather than a sequence of plots adding each point in turn since R treats the loop as a single expression.

Comment: Don't I need to use library(animation) from the R code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained the graphics manual, only plots from high-level plotting commands (e.g. `plot.new()`) and complete expressions are recorded. That means if you have multiple low-level plot changes in a for-loop, these changes will not be recorded one by one, because the for-loop in only *one* R expression. That is what Figure 4 in the manual illustrates.

If you want to create an animation from a for-loop, there must be high-level plotting commands in the loop. Figure 7 in the manual is such an example.

In your case, you have to move the `plot()` call into the loop:

```
x = 1:2
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  plot(x, x, type = "n")
  points(x[1:i], x[1:i])
}
```

Yes, this looks like a serious waste of resource, and the "natural" way should be adding points one by one as you did, instead of opening a new plot and drawing points from `1` to `i`, but there is no way to detect low-level graphical changes inside a single R expression.

Comment: I was hoping somebody had figured out a work-around to what was presented in the manual. I guess not.